# How to exact pattern matches?

Tags: python, regex

I have a file list like this: `aaa.txt bbb.doc ccc.gjf ddd.exe`. I want the file whoes extention is `gjf`. For some reasons, this file can not be the first or the last file in the file list. In other words, there must be a space before and after the file.
However, I tried many regular expressions and can not get the file:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\s+(.*?gjf) ')
print pattern.findall('aaa.txt bbb.doc ccc.gjf ddd.exe')
```

> ```
> result: ['bbb.doc ccc.gjf']
> ```

```
pattern = re.compile(r' (.*?gjf) ')
print pattern.findall('aaa.txt bbb.doc ccc.gjf ddd.exe')
```

> ```
> result: ['bbb.doc ccc.gjf']
> ```

what should I do?

Answer (score 5):

I do not think regex is entirely necessary for this problem:

```
s = 'aaa.txt bbb.doc ccc.gjf ddd.exe'
final_data = [i for i in s.split()[1:-1] if i.endswith('.gjf')]
```

Output:

```
['ccc.gjf']
```

However, if you really need regex, you can try this:

```
import re
s = 'aaa.txt eee.gjf bbb.doc ccc.gjf ddd.exe'
final_data = re.findall("(?<!^)[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.gjf(?!$)", s)
```

Output:

```
['eee.gjf', 'ccc.gjf']
```